# Stacked bar chart reversed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js

I have little problem.
I created a bar chart , you can see it on this link:
[Stacked Bar Chart](http://tinyurl.com/po5hifo)

The problem is that if you refresh 2-3 times this page , it will reverse the bar charts like that:
[image]

why it's happen?
and how can I solve it?

Thanks!!

and the CSV file in this link:
[CSV file](http://tinyurl.com/q8qig4)

Comment: Could you show us code ?

Comment: Hi , The code that I put in jsfiddle not working for me cause the CSV file..
you can see source code in this link:
http://132.75.252.107/~tal_avital/stack.html

and this is the csv file:
http://132.75.252.107/~tal_avital/fullpath.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put all your processing inside the asynchronous d3.csv() call.

See this [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/sNOe2twUuljvvP20Lure?p=preview).

```
d3.csv("fullpath.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        arr[d.User_ID] = 0;
    });

    var margin = {
    //...rest of code...
```